# Grails events list when packing war

Tags: grails, war

I'm looking for events list of cases when packing war files.
The main cause is to create a file with a build id of my system when the build is done.

I tried to look for it using google, but I didn't find any.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. Can you rephrase your question and give examples or explain what you are trying to produce/do?

Comment: In every finishing of war creation in my project, I would like to generate some build number id which should be kept in a file.
This process should be made when finishing creating the WAR file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using this:

def webAppDir = "${basedir}" + "/web-app/"  
def buildNumber = new SimpleDateFormat("yMMdd.HHmm").format(new Date())
new File(webAppDir + "buildNumber.properties").delete()
def file = new File(webAppDir + "buildNumber.properties")
file.append("app.buildNumber = " + buildNumber)

Comment: in which file did you put it ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments it sounds like you want a custom Gant script that you can use. You can create your own scripts using the [create-script](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Command%20Line/create-script.html) command.

Assuming you use `grails create-script MyCustomBuild`

A very simple example of what your script may look like:

```
// MyCustomBuild.groovy
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsWar")

target(main: "Create a WAR and append to text file") {
    // build the WAR file
    war()

    // Append to the file
    // insert your logic here for creating your build number
    def buildNumber = new Date().getTime()
    def file = new File("somefile.txt")
    file.append("Build #: ${buildNumber}\n")
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

Once you create this script you can use it from the grails console or command line as such:

```
grails mycustombuild
```